# How can you reverse-engineer failed eigen-problems to a successful solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's suppose you're trying to solve a differential equation, like

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t) = f(t)$$

and you take a guess like $f(t) = \exp(-\lambda t^2).$ You then find out it doesn't work because this results in $-2 \lambda t = 1$, because the result is either still dependent on time, or, the trivial solution $\lambda = 0.$

So my broad question is this: what is the process by which I can reverse engineer this, or any failed eigen-problem, so that I can correctly deduce how I need to modify my definition of $f(t)$ to yield a correct solution?

In other words, what is it about this failed eigen-result $-2 \lambda t = 1$ which tells me explicitly that I must take $f(\sqrt{t})$ to obtain a successful solution? Is there a technique perhaps involving integrating factors that may work?

Comment: Could you give more examples of differential equations you might wish to solve with such a technique, since you presumably already know how to solve this one?

Comment: How about the system $x'(t) = y(t)^2, y'(t) = x(t)^2$.

Comment: It should be $-2\lambda t=1$

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I had a slightly different function in my notes before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like [Perturbation Theory][1].
$$
\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi=E\psi
$$
is the Schrodinger equation for a quantum simple harmonic oscillator.
 Now suppose you turn on an electric field: this modifies the potential energy adding a term of $-E_0x$ and the new equation is
$$
\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2-E_0x\right)\psi=E\psi
$$
You can solve this by completing the square and variable substitution to get the equation in the original form  of the QSHO then use the same old techniques to solve it. Alternatively, you can use perturbation theory.

First solve the original equation to get the eigenvectors and values that solve the original equation $\phi_k$. We expect to add small change to get the solutions for the new equation.

Denote the original Hamiltonian as
$$
\hat{H}\psi=\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi.
$$ Denote the part that gets modified as $\hat{h}=-E_0x.$
Let $\Psi_j$ represent solutions to the new Hamiltonian:
$$
\Psi_j=\sum C_{jk}(\phi_k+\lambda\eta_k)
$$ where $\eta_k$ are correction terms to the function. 
The new eigenvalue problem becomes
$$
(\hat{H}+\mu\hat{h})\Psi_j=(\hat{H}+\mu\hat{h})\sum C_{jk}(\phi_k+\lambda\eta_k).
$$
Using orthogonality and assuming $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are small allows you to use a Taylor expansion analog to find the corrected eigenvalues and eigenstates. The solutions to the original problem $\phi_k$ are used to approximate the new solutions.

For this particular problem the perturbation theory solution and the analytical solution are identical, but that is usually not the case.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response, I had not considered perturbation theory in this before, would you willing to illustrate how to apply the concepts to this specific $e^{- \lambda t^2}$ problem?